# Oracle: How to drop role, which has no owner with admin option

Tags: oracle, privileges, role

I have a role in oracle database. The role was created by some user (unknown), but currently no user has admin option on the role.

1. I know that the role exists:
   `SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLES WHERE ROLE = 'roleName';`
   The query returns the role.
2. No user has admin option
   `SELECT rp.grantee, rp.granted_role, rp.admin_option
   FROM dba_role_privs rp
   JOIN dba_users u
     ON rp.grantee = u.username
   WHERE admin_option = 'YES'
     AND rp.granted_role = 'roleName'
   ORDER BY grantee, granted_role;`
   The query returns nothing
3. **I need drop the role.**

I don't know, how this situation appeared, because for all other roles, some user with admin option exists. Could someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: So, did you try to drop that role? What happened?

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: What user are you connected to when trying to drop that role?

Comment: The user has following system privileges: `CREATE VIEW,
CREATE SYNONYM,
ALTER SESSION,
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE,
CREATE ROLE,
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY,
CREATE TABLE,
CREATE SEQUENCE,
CREATE TRIGGER,
CREATE SESSION,
CREATE JOB`

Comment: if role doesn't belong to that user, he can't drop it - he'd need additional DROP ANY ROLE privilege (unless I'm wrong). Perhaps you should post a full SQLPlus session which shows what user you are connected to, what commands you run and how Oracle responds.

Comment: I think that it's clear now. I have to contact admin, because I haven't user with DROP ANY ROLE. But still I don't understand one thing. Some user created the role and now the role doesn't belong to any user. It looks, that the user was deleted after he had created the role.

Comment: A role doesn't belong to anyone; that's how Oracle made it.

Comment: Of course...I used same word as you in previous comment...I meant if I create a role, I get admin option automatically... But in this case no one has admin option...